# How to disable js Minification in gulp when using npm gulp-minify-inline plugin

Tags: gulp, gulp-minify

Am using gulp-minify-inline plugin to only compress inline javascript and css for sales force pages and component which is basally html code.

Am trying to disable the js minification via option. Could any one suggest what attribute i need it as false?

Plugin url: https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-minify-inline
Document: https://github.com/terser/terser

```
var minifyInline = require('gulp-minify-inline');

var options = {
  js: {
    output: {
      comments: true
    }, 
    minify: false -----> Not working 
  },
  jsSelector: 'script[type!="text/x-handlebars-template"]',
  css: {
    level: {1: {specialComments: 0}}
  },
  cssSelector: 'style[data-do-not-minify!="true"]'
};

gulp.task('minify-inline', function() {
  gulp.src('src/*.html')
    .pipe(minifyInline(options))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/'))
});
```

Answer (score 1):

> js contains parameters to pass to terser.minify() (for documetation refer to the project homepage). Set it to false to disable JS minification globally

You might try `js: false`